# Is plugin_LTLIBRARIES a buildin variable like lib_LTLIBRARIES and noinst_LTLIBRARIES?

Tags: build-automation, autotools, automake

Recently I read the source code of strongswan. And I found this piece of script in one Makefile.am. I didn't see `plugin_LTLIBRARIES` before. I searched on the internet. Most of the result is Makefile.am files. Is is a M4 macro or a buildin variable? What's the usage of it?

```
if MONOLITHIC
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libstrongswan-socket-default.la
else
plugin_LTLIBRARIES = libstrongswan-socket-default.la
endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any automake variable of the form `foo_PRIMARY` installs to `$(foodir)`. `$(plugindir)` might be set via `AC_SUBST` in `configure.ac`.

`m4` isn't used in handling `Makefile.am`. They're parsed with `automake`, a perl program, because the logic involved in building the `Makefile.in` template is much more subtle than straight macro expansion.

Comment: I found `ARG_WITH_SUBST([plugindir], [${ipsecdir%/}/plugins], [set the installation path of plugins])` in configure.ac. Right?

Comment: I think so: https://github.com/strongswan/strongswan/blob/master/m4/macros/with.m4